# Determine sun elevation without header file?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine, bhuvan

I have some AWiFS and LISS-III data that I'm trying to convert from at-sensor spectral radiance to top-of-atmosphere reflectance.  The problem is, the data didn't come with any header file.  All I have is an XML document but it doesn't provide any sun-earth geometry.  I could use something like: http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/AltAz.php knowing the acquisition date, but I can't determine the time of acquisition.  I'm using ERDAS Imagine 2013 and the data-sets were obtained from Bhuvan Gateway to Indian Earth Observation at http://bhuvan-noeda.nrsc.gov.in/download/download/download.php